# Upgrading rails scope rails 2.2 to rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am having issue with converting the rails 2 scope syntax in rails 4<

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
 
    has_many :locations
 
end
 
 
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   
  belongs_to :region
   
  **scope :permitted, lambda {|p_id|
    {:joins => "left join person_locations pl on pl.location_id = locations.id",
      :conditions => ["pl.person_id = ? AND pl.active = 'Yes'", p_id]}
  }**
   
  #where pl = person_location
  
end

class PersonLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
 
     belongs_to :location
 
end

class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  
   def index
    
     **@locations = @region.locations.permitted(current_person.id).active.all(:order => "name")**
     
      respond_to do |format|
       
        format.html # index.html.erb
    
       end
   
    end
 
end

- ***List item***

Comment: You never mentioned what the issue is. Please give more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
scope :permitted, ->(p_id) { joins("left join person_locations pl on pl.location_id = locations.id").where("pl.person_id = ? AND pl.active = 'Yes'", p_id) }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
scope :permitted, lambda { |id| 
  joins('left join person_locations pl on pl.location_id = locations.id').
  where(pl: { person_id: id, active: 'Yes' })
}
```

Or if it is possible to add an association to `person_locations` into your `Location` model:

```
has_many :person_locations

scope :permitted, lambda { |id| 
  joins(:person_locations).where(person_locations: { person_id: id, active: 'Yes' })
}
```